# How to search for a string or word in Ansible results?

Tags: ansible

I wrote a a task which just print if restart required. I have this yum module output and I need to extract the word "Complete | or_some_other_word" and this task will only run if aforementioned words exists.

```yaml
TASK [deploying_security_updates : Installed Packages] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.8.26] => {
    "yum_update": {
        "changed": true,
        "changes": {
            "installed": [],
            "updated": [
                [
                    "xz",
                    "5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64 from rhel-remote"
                ],
                [
                    "xz-libs",
                    "5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64 from rhel-remote"
                ]
            ]
        },
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "",
        "rc": 0,
        "results": [
            "Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-\n              : manager\nThis system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.\n --> device-mapper-persistent-data-0.7.3-3.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> 7:device-mapper-event-1.02.170-6.el7_9.5.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> libgnomekbd-3.26.0-3.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> cryptsetup-python-2.0.3-3.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> PackageKit-gstreamer-plugin-1.1.10-2.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> libstoragemgmt-1.6.2-4.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> PackageKit-gtk3-module-1.1.10-2.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> 7:device-mapper-event-1.02.149-8.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> setroubleshoot-plugins-3.0.67-3.el7.noarch from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> libdrm-2.4.91-3.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> mesa-dri-drivers-18.3.4-12.el7_9.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> subscription-manager-plugin-container-1.24.51-1.el7_9.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> firewalld-0.6.3-13.el7_9.noarch from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> gdb-7.6.1-114.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> grubby-8.28-26.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> hostname-3.13-3.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> 32:bind-libs-lite-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.9.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> abrt-dbus-2.1.11-52.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> unzip-6.0-21.el7.x86_64 from @rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> realmd-0.16.1-12.el7_9.1.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> 2:shadow-utils-4.1.5.1-25.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> libreport-2.1.11-53.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> 1:grub2-tools-minimal-2.02-0.87.el7_9.6.x86_64 from @rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> 1:grub2-pc-modules-2.02-0.87.el7_9.6.noarch from @rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> 1:make-3.82-23.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> anaconda-gui-21.48.22.147-1.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> 2:gedit-3.28.1-1.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> iptables-1.4.21-35.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> gnome-shell-extension-window-list-3.28.1-14.el7.noarch from @rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> plymouth-0.8.9-0.31.20140113.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 re\n --> gnome-settings-daemon-3.28.1-11.el7_9.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> 10:qemu-kvm-1.5.3-175.el7_9.6.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> libcap-2.22-9.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> libvirt-daemon-driver-nodedev-4.5.0-36.el7_9.3.x86_64 from @rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> libblockdev-swap-2.18-3.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> tzdata-2018e-3.el7.noarch from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> langtable-0.0.31-4.el7.noarch from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> librdmacm-22.4-6.el7_9.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.1.11-53.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> mesa-libglapi-18.3.4-12.el7_9.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> sos-3.6-9.el7.noarch from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> anaconda-tui-21.48.22.159-1.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> 3:irqbalance-1.0.7-12.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> libreport-plugin-ureport-2.1.11-53.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> systemd-219-78.el7_9.5.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> python2-blockdev-2.18-5.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> pulseaudio-module-bluetooth-10.0-5.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> ipset-libs-6.38-2.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> lshw-B.02.18-17.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> libblockdev-crypto-2.18-5.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> libffi-3.0.13-19.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n2 package(s) needed (+0 related) for security, out of 401 available\nResolving Dependencies\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package xz.x86_64 0:5.2.2-1.el7 will be updated\n---> Package xz.x86_64 0:5.2.2-2.el7_9 will be an update\n---> Package xz-libs.x86_64 0:5.2.2-1.el7 will be updated\n---> Package xz-libs.x86_64 0:5.2.2-2.el7_9 will be an update\n--> Finished Dependency Resolution\n\nDependencies Resolved\n\n================================================================================\n Package         Arch           Version               Repository           Size\n================================================================================\nUpdating:\n xz              x86_64         5.2.2-2.el7_9         rhel-remote         229 k\n xz-libs         x86_64         5.2.2-2.el7_9         rhel-remote         103 k\n\nTransaction Summary\n================================================================================\nUpgrade  2 Packages\n\nTotal download size: 332 k\nDownloading packages:\nNo Presto metadata available for rhel-remote\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nTotal                                              1.3 MB/s | 332 kB  00:00     \nRunning transaction check\nRunning transaction test\nTransaction test succeeded\nRunning transaction\n  Updating   : xz-libs-5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64                                 1/4 \n  Updating   : xz-5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64                                      2/4 \n  Cleanup    : xz-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64                                        3/4 \n  Cleanup    : xz-libs-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64                                   4/4 \n  Verifying  : xz-libs-5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64                                 1/4 \n  Verifying  : xz-5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64                                      2/4 \n  Verifying  : xz-libs-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64                                   3/4 \n  Verifying  : xz-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64                                        4/4 \n\nUpdated:\n  xz.x86_64 0:5.2.2-2.el7_9            xz-libs.x86_64 0:5.2.2-2.el7_9           \n\nComplete!\n"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Now what is your question? You can `grep Complete` of the output and start the script depending on the return value of the `grep`. So what? Is it possible that the output could contain something like `The Task Could Not Complete!`?

Comment: Why don't you use the built in method of detecting if a reboot is required? This was already suggested in an answer to your last question.

Comment: @Philippos, at the moment i will only use, Complete and Kernel and based on this condition it will reboot the machine but later i will add task based on different condition and it will not reboot the machine

Answer (score 5):

You may have a look into

**Documentation**

- [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)
- [Testing strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings)
- [Jinja2 Template Designer Documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#other-operators)

and could use

```yaml
when: "'Complete' in yum_update.results"
```

or

```yaml
when: yum_update.results is search('Complete')
```

**Further Q&A**

- [Run an Ansible task only when the variable contains a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496911/)